# Automatically stamping UserName of the User who created the a Sales record in the sales table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I want to create a ASP.NET MVC web application, which includes an Admin account and few user account, for registering and login I'm using Default Account Model and controller. Can anyone tell me how can I AutoStamp the username of the user who created the sales record also how can I view this in my index page.
For sales I have Sales Model which has

```
{
public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Po { get; set; }
    public long So { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Store the username in a `Session Variable` and store it in the table while saving the data.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'm very new to asp.net could you provide me with some example or reference?

Answer (score 0):

Store the username in the session.

```
Session["UserId"] = usernameThatLoggedIn
```

Later you can access it with

```
Session["UserId"]
```

If you are not inside a Controller you can access it via

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["UserId"]
```